# Error when I click on some of the products

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog

I am facing an error when I click on some of the products in CMS but I am able to see the products in Merchandising manager.

Because of this I am not able to rebuild indexes also.

```
Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentNullException Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value Source: Newtonsoft.Json
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions.Value[T,U](IEnumerable`1 value)
    at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.ReadOnlyCatalogDataProvider.c.b__7_0(JToken x)
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
    at Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.DataProvider.ReadOnlyCatalogDataProvider.GetItemVersions(ItemDefinition item, CallContext context)
    at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.GetItemVersions(ItemDefinition item, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
    at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.LoadVersions(ItemDefinition definition, Language language)
    at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetVersions(ItemInformation itemInformation, Language language)
    at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetLatestVersion(ItemInformation itemInformation, Language language)
    at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.GetItemData(ID itemID, Language language, Version version)    
    at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.GetItem(ID , Language, Version , Database )    
    at Sitecore.Nexus.Data.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.Execute(ID , Language, Version , Database )    
    at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataCommands.GetItemCommand.DoExecute()    
    at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()    
    at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database)    
    at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.GetItem(ID itemId, Language language, Version version, Database database, SecurityCheck securityCheck)    
    at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.ItemProvider.GetItem.GetItemUnderTestProcessor.Process(GetItemArgs args)    
    at (Object , Object )
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like your Sitecore XP couldn't communicate with Sitecore XC. Check your 
`commerceEngineConfiguration` in `\App_Config\Include\Y.Commerce.Engine\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config` (by default)

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as some products are working @AndreiPaliakou.

Comment: Try to delete and update data templates in Sitecore XP

Comment: Tried this many times but it doesn't help. I have only tried to update data templates. Last time when I tried to tried delete data templates then I was not able to regenerate it using update data templates. Then I had to restore commerce shared and global Dbs @AndreiPaliakou

Comment: So if you not able to regenerate data templates then your problem is more related to composer templates, which can have circular dependencies

Comment: Update data template is working. Only if I delete data template and then try Update data template, it does not work @AndreiPaliakou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to a custom template which had to be inherited in the product template. After inheriting the template I rebuilt indexes and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the environment and initialize again, if nothing else worked for you. Use postman APIs to

1. Clean Environment.
2. Ensure\Sync default content paths.
3. Initialize Environment.
4. Import Catalogs (with publishing).

Make sure you export your catalog before running these APIs.